# XSLT add number to variable

Tags: variables, xslt

i have XSLT, where i have variables (DPH5 and DPH22). On start the variables are null.
After that i add tu this variables sum od DPH.
This is part of my XML:

```
<TeloTR>
   <TYP_CASTKY>DP</TYP_CASTKY>
   <PROCENTO_DANE>21.0</PROCENTO_DANE>
   <CASTKA>100.720</CASTKA>
</TeloTR>
<TeloTR>
   <TYP_CASTKY>DP</TYP_CASTKY>
   <PROCENTO_DANE>15.0</PROCENTO_DANE>
   <CASTKA>562.720</CASTKA>
</TeloTR>
<TeloTR>
   <TYP_CASTKY>DP</TYP_CASTKY>
   <PROCENTO_DANE>15.0</PROCENTO_DANE>
   <CASTKA>66375.720</CASTKA>
</TeloTR>
<TeloTR>
   <TYP_CASTKY>DP</TYP_CASTKY>
   <PROCENTO_DANE>15.0</PROCENTO_DANE>
   <CASTKA>845.720</CASTKA>
</TeloTR>
```

This is my variables:

```
<xsl:variable name="DPH5" select="0" />
<xsl:variable name="DPH22" select="0" />
```

This is part of my code:

```
<xsl:for-each select="TeloTR">
    <xsl:if test="TYP_CASTKY='DP'">
       <xsl:if test="PROCENTO_DANE='15.0'">
          <xsl:variable name="DPH5" select="$DPH5 + number(@CASTKA) " />  
       </xsl:if>
       <xsl:if test="PROCENTO_DANE='21.0'">
          <xsl:variable name="DPH22" select="$DPH22 + number(@CASTKA) " />  
       </xsl:if>                    
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

But i have this error:

```
Error:XSLTProcessor::transformToXml() [<a href='xsltprocessor.transformtoxml'>
xsltprocessor.transformtoxml</a>]: XSLT-variable: Redefinition of variable 'DPH5'.
```

Have you any ideas how could i add values to variables? Thanks

Comment: In XSLT, variable are 'immutable' and cannot be changed once set. So if you have initially set them to '0' then they stay set to '0'. All your code is trying to do is re-define new variables with the same name. As the new variables are in the same scope as the existing variables, an error occurs. It would help if you explained what you are trying to achieve (by showing your input XML and your expected output), then an alternative approach can possibly be given. Thank you!

Comment: @Tim C  I editet first post. I want to sum all CASTKA in PROCENTO_DANE 15 and 21 separate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, In XSLT, variable are 'immutable' and cannot be changed once set.

However you can solve your particular problem by using the `sum` function, to sum all the nodes (or attributes) that match a certain condition.

Try these two variable declarations

```
  <xsl:variable name="DPH5" select="sum(TeloTR[TYP_CASTKY='DP'][PROCENTO_DANE = 15.0]/CASTKA) " />  
  <xsl:variable name="DPH22" select="sum(TeloTR[TYP_CASTKY='DP'][PROCENTO_DANE = 22.0]/CASTKA) " />
```

Note that `CASTKA` is an element in your XML, so you shouldn't use the `@` prefix which denotes an attribute.

Alternatively, to avoid a little repetition, you can do this

```
  <xsl:variable name="TeloTR" select="TeloTR[TYP_CASTKY='DP']" />
  <xsl:variable name="DPH5" select="sum($TeloTR[PROCENTO_DANE = 15.0]/CASTKA) " />  
  <xsl:variable name="DPH22" select="sum($TeloTR[PROCENTO_DANE = 21.0]/CASTKA) " />
```